# Using the flutter listing method on another page and using it on the relevant page

Tags: java

I have defined a list as below under my stful widget and listed these Lists by index number in listview.builder. Since this list will be too much, I want to write it on another page and import it into the relevant page, but I do not know exactly how to do this. It is possible to import 1 list from another page, but I get an error when I get a list number 2, I guess this is due to initState. but I need to use it this way, how can I do it.

```
1.) List listItem = [
"Genel Sıralama",
"Nüfusa Göre",
"Savunma Bütçesine Göre",
"Tank Sayısına Göre",
"Uçak Sayısına Göre",
"Donanma Gücüne Göre",
"Toprak Büyüklüğüne Göre",
"Petrol Rezervlerine Göre",
];



 List<genelsiralama> _genelsiralama;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _genelsiralama = [
      genelsiralama(
        "assets/anasayfa/bayraklar/amerika.png",
        "Amerika Birleşik Devletleri",
        "329,256,465",
        almanya(),
      ),
      genelsiralama(
        "assets/anasayfa/bayraklar/rusya.png",
        "Rusya",
        "142,122,776",
        almanya(),
      ),

ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: _genelsiralama.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Card(
                                  elevation: 4.0,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          child: InkWell(
                                            onDoubleTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      _genelsiralama[index]
                                                          .yolu),
                                            ),
                                            onTap: () =>
                                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                    .showSnackBar(
                                              SnackBar(
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                                                content: Text(
                                                  _genelsiralama[index]
                                                          .ulkeadi +
                                                      " Sayfasına Gitmek için Çift Tıklayın",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            onTapCancel: () {
                                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                  .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          Colors.black54,
                                                      content: new Text(
                                                        'Hay Aksi Tamda ' +
                                                            _genelsiralama[
                                                                    index]
                                                                .ulkeadi +
                                                            ' Sayfasına Gidiyordun',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontSize: 15,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .bold),
                                                      )));
                                            },
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                                _genelsiralama[index].bayrak),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        ListTile(
                                          leading: Icon(
                                            Icons.people,
                                            size: 35,
                                            color: Colors.red,
                                          ),
                                          title: Text(
                                            _genelsiralama[index].ulkeadi,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          subtitle: Text(
                                            "Nufüs : " +
                                                _genelsiralama[index].nufus,
                                          ),
                                          trailing: CircleAvatar(
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                                            child: Text(
                                              (index + 1).toString(),
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              })
```